# Puppy Showing Signs of Aggression Towards Other Dogs - Should I Expose Him to More Situations or Not?

Tags: dogs, aggression, play

My 14-week old puppy is starting to show a bit of aggression towards other dogs -- if they're close enough he sometimes barks/growls if they're separated, or if they're playing at puppy kindergarten it may break into a fight that we need to split up.

From what I've read on here and other websites, it's hard to differentiate whether to attempt to expose him to more positive social dog interactions since he's still a puppy -- or if we're at the point where I should attempt to keep him away from dogs altogether until he shows signs of improvement.

Can anyone help shed some light on this? Seems like slowly introducing him back to dogs when he's calmer is certainly a good idea but all I've also read is how extremely important puppy socialization is.

Comment: I think there are probably scientifically researched answers to this we can find on Google Scholar. Having said that, I would guess that you have to balance socialization vs accidentally getting him used to fighting by repeating it all the time. My ex gf was a psychologist and she had this problem with a rescue so she used aggressive negative verbal reinforcement to stop the growling (just saying NO aggressively then rewarding them when they stop growling). Maybe you can combine the verbal reinforcement with some pheromones or pills from the vet to help the puppy relax until they are ready.